# Binding to a comparison in Ember view

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a value in my controller than I want to use to bind to for a dynamic class.

```
isSelected: (->
    this.get('selectedConference') == '1A'
  ).property('selectedConference')
```

but instead of 1A i want it to compare it to the value being looped over in the each block.

```
  {{each conference in controller.reverseConferences}}
    <li>
      <a>
        {{isSelected}}
```

how would i pass {{this}} to isSelected?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you would need to use `itemController` of the `each` helper and the `needs` property on your conference controller. Here is a jsbin that will help you: http://jsbin.com/atomuy/3/.

The `itemController` allows to wrap your Conference Model into a Controller and create the `isSelected` property that you would need in your template. Every time you click on a conference, the `select` action will be triggered and the conference passed will be set as `selected` conference in the `ConferencesController`. Every `ConferenceController` observe the selected conference. `isSelected` property will change if it happens to be the same as the one passed. And the data binding keep everything updated for you.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The solution here was to create a view and do my bindings in that

```
App.TeamsConferencesView = Ember.View.extend
  templateName: "teams/conferences"
  selectedBinding: 'controller.selectedConference'
  loadingBinding: 'controller.loadingData'
  ConferenceItemView: Ember.View.extend
    tagName: 'li'
    classNameBindings: 'isActive:active'.w()
    isActive: (->
        this.get('content') == this.get('parentView.selected');
    ).property('item', 'parentView.selected').cacheable()
```

now when I updated the selectedConference in my controller it is bound to my view and the appropriate item is activated.

My emblem template looks like this

```
each conference in controller.reverseConferences
  view view.ConferenceItemView contentBinding="conference"
    linkTo teams.conferences conference
      conference
```